# Changing input type after event

Tags: javascript, django, events

I'm trying to change the input type in a form from 'hidden' to 'text' after a Javascript variable has a value. My current code is this:

```
var currentUser;

var getButton = document.getElementById("button");
getButton.addEventListener("click",getUser,false);
function getUser(event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("username");{
        if(user.value !=="") {
            currentUser = user.value;
        }
    event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(currentUser.value!=="") {
        document.getElementById("message").type="text";
    }
}
```

My HTML is this:

```
<form method = "post">
            {% if username %}
            <label>{{ username }}</label>
            <input id="message" type="text" size="70" name="message" />
            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="{{ username }}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="{{ timestamp }}" />
            {% else %}
            <label>Pick a username: </label>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="username" id="username" />
            {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" value="send" id="button" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? At the moment, whenever I run the code, it gets stuck on 'username', and the 'message' box doesn't appear.

Comment: have you tried removing those two invalid braces?

Comment: Apart from that, changing the type of input elements is prohibited at least by IE. No one's sure whether bug or feature.

Comment: You can also hide element by changing `display` of it or its container.

Comment: I tried removing the two invalid braces (Thank you Bergi!) but it's still not working. I'm still fiddling with it, I'll post a more coherent response once I get it working, or I really have no idea what's happening. ilvar - I'm trying to get the input to actually appear in the first place, is the problem. I'm not sure that setting a display will help.

Comment: Try it through Jquery `Show/Hide`, it helps you

Comment: It seems your "username" input does not have an "id" attribute, when it's created as hidden input.
So var user = document.getElementById("username"); does not get it

Comment: And your js does not seem to be working at all. Weird curly brace is coming after .getElementById("username"); It should raise a syntax error i guess